# Iteration out of sync

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as my backend. I am trying to load an object in the background which works fine, but these objects have a pointer to an image. The problem is, that in order to query the images in the image class, i pass a ParseObject in order to get which object the image is pointing to like this:

```
ParseObject advertToGetImageFrom = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Advert", advertList.get(j).getObjectId());
```

However, my log shows this result

> D/app: DT34J9zFKI
>
> D/app: dAqVrnZ1rf
>
> D/app: bNtIfOCqeE
>
> D/app: Images loaded: 1
>
> D/app: Images loaded: 1
>
> D/app: Images loaded: 1

Which is reasonable since the loading is async. However, all the returned images are the same? Why is this happening? Here is the entire call:

```
for (int j = 0; j < titleMap.size(); j++){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Image");
    ParseObject advertToGetImageFrom = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Advert", objectList.get(j).getObjectId());
    Log.d("app", advertToGetImageFrom.getObjectId());
    query2.whereEqualTo("advertId", advertToGetImageFrom);

    query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> imageList, ParseException e) {
            // commentList now has the comments for myPost
            Log.d("app", "Images loaded: " + imageList.size());
                if (imageList != null) {
                    ParseFile pFile = (ParseFile) imageList.get(0).get("image");

                pFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                    
                        Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(data);
                        ParseObject advertID = imageList.get(0).getParseObject("advertId");
                                                imageMap.put(advertID.getObjectId(), bmp);
                        
                        if (imageMap.size() == titleMap.size())
                            updateCardView();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familliar with parse.com but I can hazard a guess.

I suspect your problem is with the line:

```
                           ParseObject advertID = imageList.get(0).getParseObject("advertId");
```

Here you are accessing the `imageList` that was provided to the `done` callback of your `findInBackground` invocation. The problem is that you are now in the `done` callback of a `getDataInBackground` invocation and although the `imageList` is `final` that does not make it immutable and has probably changed since the original call.

This doesn't seem like a terrible thing at first sight as this should only affect the `advertID` but think about that further and you may see the problem.

I **think** the solution **could be** to grab a local copy of the data that might change. Something like:

```
                    pFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        // **** Grab the ParseObject befor it gets changed.
                        ParseObject theParseObject = imageList.get(0);
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {

                                Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(data);
                                // **** Refer to the grabbed ParseObject not the changing outer one.
                                ParseObject advertID = theParseObject.getParseObject("advertId");
```

If that doesnt fix your issue then I feel certain it will be something like this.

Comment: You are totally right. When i log the pFile it is different, but the data from the done method returns the same byte array. However, i dont see how to catch the file between the getDataInBackground and the done method. There doesn't seem to be a file to catch? I have to decode the byte array i get from the done method, but it seems impossible, since it is changing too fast?